# Iterating a HashMap in Freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

How do I iterate over a hashmap in Freemarker. I am using the 2.3.23 version and I am unable to get the value from the hashmap. I am using the following:

```
<#list hashMap?keys as key>
  ${key} = ${hashMap.get(key)}
<#list>
```

I have even tried the following:

```
<#list hashMap?keys as key>
  ${key} = ${hashMap[key]}
<#list>
```

It says that the value is null. However, I checked the data and there is a value for every key. I cannot upgrade the freemarker version to 2.3.25

Could someone help me with this.

Comment: Which type has your hashmap?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the problem is that your keys aren't `String`-s, but some Java objects other than mere numbers/dates/booleans. Such "miscellaneous" objects are usable as FTL strings, so that you can print them directly (and internally that calls `obj.toString()`). Thus `hashMap[key]` won't complain that `key` is not a FTL string (because it is), instead it basically does `hashMap.get(key.toString())`, and there you have your `null`.

Since you can't update to 2.3.25, where you could use `<#list hashMap as key, value>`, you have to use `?api` (and I hope you can enable calling `?api` in the configuration):

```
<#list hashMap?api.entrySet() as ent>
  ${ent.key} = ${ent.value}
</#list>
```